# Why is my Azure VPN Gateway-NAT rule not working?

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, nat, site-to-site-vpn

I have a very simple scenario, Azure Vnet with a subnets 10.140.1.0/24 (GatewaySubnet, SKU=Gw2 gen1) and 10.140.10.0/24 (VirtualMachineSubnet). Then an OnPrem network with 10.190.0.0/16.

I have a successful Site2Site connection to the OnPrem network. I can ping the 10.190.x.x. from a VM in my Azure VirtualMachineSubnet (with IP 10.140.10.4). But when I introduce a NAT rule this no longer works. The OnPrem device is only allowing traffic from my VirtualMachineSubnet(+an extension on that range), but I want to widen this on my side, hence the NAT.

I tried to simplify this to the most simple NAT rule, a rule that does not actually translate.
So the NAT rule I have is:
Static, EgressSnat, InternalMapping: 10.140.10.4/32, ExternalMapping: 10.140.10.4/32, meaning, there should be no change in IP.

**The moment** I link this NAT rule to the S2S-connection the pinging stops working. Whats going on?

It looks like the moment I link **any** NAT rule to the connection, the connection stops working.

Note: Routebased, no policytraffic filters, no BGP, I also tried to translate the whole VirtualMachineSubnet to VirtualMachineSubnet and same result. I have also tried completely random Subnets that are not even in use, yet the pinging from my Vm-Subnet stops working. Also tried adding an Ingress rule mapping 1:1 the onPrem IP range, not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when using Windows Server RRAS as your on-prem device.

If so, by creating an internal and external (with NAT) rule in RRAS, you will be given the two-way communication.

Also, you could get away with using the basic SKU (cheapest) virtual network gateway which is useful if you are just testing things out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I'm not using RRAS on OnPrem, its an Palo Alto Gateway

Answer (score 0):

where you able to spot any root cause for this? I have a similar behavior, after setting up NAT rules and linking them in Azure, I can't open the comnnection that was working before any longer

Comment: unfortunately no, I went a different route where NAT was no longer needed (unrelated to azure vpn)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/531270)